# bind data to DOM in D3JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My code is very simple and looks like the following:

```
function draw(data){
    svg.data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("fill",data.[i-th].color)
        .attr("d", function(d) { 
         return design(d.x,d.y);
           });

    }


d3.json("data/dataset.json")
     .then(function(data) {
          draw(data); //is an array of elements x,y,color
      })
```

In the `draw` function data is correctly bound to DOM, but my problem is the attribute `fill` because I would like that it takes the i-th elements of the data array.

Comment: To modify the fill attributes of the `i-th` element, you will need a function (with an index variable) that iterates over the data.  For example: `.attr("fill", function(d, i){ if ( i === sometarget ) { ... } else {...}) ` (change `sometarget` to the value you want). If `i-th` is a series of elements, then adjust the condition to look for a range of values.

Comment: Just use a function to return the `.color`property: `.attr("fill", d => d.color)`. This will be executed for every datum bound to the DOM, i.e. D3 will take care that the *i*th color will be returned for the *i*th element.

Comment: Additionally, more a matter of style though, `.then(function(data) { draw(data); })` can be significantly shortend to `.then(draw)`.

Comment: Thanks, I solved. Why if data is an array of objects I need `selectAll`, while if it is a simple array such as `[3,4,5,6]` I don't need `selectAll` to bind data to DOM?

Comment: Please @altocumulus, put your response in a proper answer so it can be accepted. On the other hand, @ stackfac, probably you should open another question instead of using the comments for additional questions. In such a way, other users with a similar question could be benefit from it.